# Spring boot @RestController

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is there a step needed, like adding jars to classpath?

I followed this:

10.2.6 Quick start Spring CLI example

Here’s a really simple web application that you can use to test your installation. Create a file called app.groovy:

```
@RestController
class ThisWillActuallyRun {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {
        "Hello World!"
    }
}
```

Then simply run it from a shell:

```
$ spring run app.groovy
```

and get:

```
startup failed:
file:/home/rgupta/Documents/products/microservices/postabook/hola-springboot/app.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class ResttController,  unable to find class for annotation
@ line 1, column 1.
@ResttController
^

file:/home/rgupta/Documents/products/microservices/postabook/hola-springboot/app.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class RequestMapping ,  unable to find class for annotation
@ line 4, column 5.
@RequestMapping("/")
^

2 errors

[rgupta@rgupta hola-springboot]$
```

Comment: Is `app.groovy` really the content of your file? The error message that it is looking for `ResttController` (notice the double t) doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 1):

Change `@ResttController` in line 1 of app.groovy in your IDE to `@RestController`.

Answer (score 1):

As @da_mp said, correct the spelling of `@RestController`. Once you've done that, you will also need to add the following import statements to the top of the file:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
```

And that should solve your errors.